# getValue() from an XLS attachment in Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, xlsx

How to getValue() of Cell "A1" in an XLSX attachment (of sheet 1) received in Gmail by app script running from a google sheet? The daily gmail (with XLSX attachment) is from a particular email ID with a particular subject.

I tried various examples available. Making some silly mistake and not able to crack it.

Comment: If you are looking for specific implementations, ask specific questions. Post the code you tried, the code you found somewhere else that is converting excel files to google sheets. In this way you will also get better, faster and more specific answers but you will also learn down the road.

Answer (score 0):

### [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) is a method of the class [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app), to be used on Google spreadsheets

You cannot use it on Excel files.

If you want to use a method of `SpreadsheetApp` or the `Google Sheets API` on your file, you need to convert it first from Excel to Google Sheets.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60834484/11599789) how to convert an Excel file from a Gmail attachment to a Google sheet.

Comment: I don't think that the OP refererred to *that* `getValue()`

Comment: What would be the referred `getValue()` then?